# Suppressing resharper rename in strings

Tags: refactoring, resharper

Is there any way to suppress renaming strings after Ctr+R, Ctr+R in file, someting similar to:

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
private readonly IMyClass NONStandardConvension;
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
```

but with code like:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestIfNameNotChanged()
    {
        // ReSharper disable ??refactoring??
        var className = typeof (MyClass).Name;
        Assert.AreEqual("MyClass", className);
        // ReSharper restore ??refactoring??
    }
```

I would like to test if my scripts won't fail after applying accidental refactoring.

Comment: I do `Assert.AreEqual("M" + "yClass", className)` but the feature would be very nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no such feature in current Resharper version (7.1.3). But if you like it to come you can vote on Resharper [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-350720).